# Arduino as USB HID is slowed down when PC doesn't read events

Tags: usb, arduino-micro, linux, events, hid

I have an Arduino Micro that is acting as a HID device for a Linux PC.

I use this call to send the HID values:

`HID().SendReport(1, _values, sizeof(_values));`

This works in principle, but I noticed this issue:

If my Linux PC is not actively reading the events from the Arduino, then the Arduino is slowed down. My rotary encoders are missing signals, is one symptom.

But as soon as I read the events with my Linux PC, the Arduino loop() runs at full speed again.

I suspect that this is due to recv/send time out delays in the USB core code? Because I noticed this in USBCore.cpp:

`u8 timeout = 250;               // 250ms timeout on send? TODO`

Anyway, I tried to solve this issue in the following manners:

Check for configuration and suspension with:

```
     if (USBDevice.configured())
      if (!USBDevice.isSuspended())
         ...
```

Which did not work.

I also tried monitoring the increments of the frame number:

```
  // See if USB shows activity.
  static uint8_t prev_fr_num = UDFNUML;
  static uint8_t num_times_idle = 0;
  uint8_t fr_num = UDFNUML;
  if (fr_num == prev_fr_num )
  {
    if (num_times_idle < 255)
      num_times_idle++;
  }
  else
  {
    num_times_idle = 0;
    prev_fr_num = fr_num;
  }
```

And then only send if num_times_idle is smaller than a threshold. Again, this did not help.

The only way to make it fast, is by reading the events with linux, like so:

`$ jstest /dev/input/js0`

or alternatively:

`$ evtest /dev/input/event5`

How can I have the USB HID stuff not slow down my loop code when the PC is not paying attention?

Thanks!

Bram

Comment: please reduce the code to smallest code that still exhibits the issue and add the code listing to your question

Comment: USB is actively polled by the host and a client can not initiate communications. Maybe it's a buffer filling up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those that hit the same issue, here is how I solved it:

Expose the `USB_SendSpace()` information in the HID interface by editing

**/usr/local/arduino-1.8.12/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/HID/src/HID.cpp**

```
u8 HID_::SendSpace(void)
{
        return USB_SendSpace(pluggedEndpoint);
}
```

And adding the interface to `class HID_` in:

**/usr/local/arduino-1.8.12/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/HID/src/HID.h**

That way, before calling `HID().SendReport()` you can check for send buffer space available by calling the `HID().SendSpace()` method.

If there is no space, just skip the SendReport() calls, and the Arduino loop() will no longer be slowed down by time outs.